# ng-show / hide with 'track by $index' not hiding by index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting, what I believe to be, an odd behaviour when adding arrays to an object in an `ng-repeat`.

Due to the "`Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed`" error I am using `track by $index` but when I try to show / hide a row everything that was added is toggled. I have tried passing the index into an `ng-click` and even setting the value directly in the `ng-click`

Here is some sample code and a <kbd>[jsFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/yMZjs/)</kbd>

HTML excerpt:

```html
<tbody ng-repeat="person in object track by $index" ng-show="person.visible">
<tr>
    <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.age }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href ng-click="togglePerson($index)">Hide</a>
    </td>
    <!-- <td>
        <a href ng-click="person.visible = !person.visible">Hide</a>
    </td> -->
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Javascript:

```javascript
myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.object = [{
            name: "Billy",
            age: 21,
            visible: true
        }];
        $scope.newEntry = {
            name: 'Ralph',
            age: 16,
            visible: true
        };
    };

    $scope.addPerson = function () {
        $scope.object.push($scope.newEntry);
    };

    $scope.togglePerson = function (index) {
        console.log(index); // Index is being passed properly
        $scope.object[index].visible = !$scope.object[index].visible;
    };
});
```

I have done quite a few visibility toggles in the past within a repeater (never with a `track by $index`) but I can't seem to determine where I went wrong. Is this even related to the tracking / array comparison?

---

**Edit**

To be clear, my demonstration is not how I am using this code. I am actually toggling a second rows visibility. I know that my demonstration is flawed since once you toggle hidden you can't toggle back.

Comment: what does `due to duplicates error` mean?

Comment: I apologize, I meant the error `Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed`

Comment: with only one item to add in demo...demo seems to work fine so not understanding issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push an object into an array it pushes the object by reference. Each time you call this

```
$scope.addPerson = function () {
        $scope.object.push($scope.newEntry);
    };
```

You are basically pushing the same object at different index positions of the array. Now this same object is repeated over in the repeater.

And when you toggle :

```
$scope.togglePerson = function (index) {
        console.log(index); // Index is being passed properly
        $scope.object[index].visible = !$scope.object[index].visible;
    };
```

you are basically setting the same objects property on all the array indexes, since the array has the same object at all the indexes.

You need to do a copy of the object before pushing it into the array so that you get a new object every single time.

```
$scope.addPerson = function () {
        $scope.object.push(angular.copy($scope.newEntry));
    };
```

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates this :

<kbd>[jsFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/yMZjs/1/)</kbd>

**NOTE :**  This has nothing to do with array `track by $index`

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks, I hadn't thought of that.